# Pgfmath misbehaving when reading negative values from table in Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath

I am astonished that when I attempt to square a number read from a table with `pgfplots`, the result has the same sign. Consider this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
   col1 col2
   -1   -2
   0    -2
   2    -3
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{data.dat}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
         xtick=data,
      ]
      \addplot table[
         x expr=\coordindex,
         y expr={
            \thisrow{col2}^2
         }
      ] {\datatable};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`col2`s values are supposed to get squared `\thisrow{col2}^2`, but it appears as if `\thisrow{col2}` expands to e.g. `-2` and the expression becomes `-2^2` and is parsed as `-(2^2)`. Also the second row seems to be wrong altogether. Is this behaviour intended and where is it documented? I find this grossly counterintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX expands `\thisrow{col2}` to `-2`, so what's eventually seen is

```
-2^2
```

which is, according to the usual conventions, `-4`. The same in the other cases.

Adding parentheses, as follows,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
   col1 col2
   -1   -2
   0    -2
   2    -3
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{data.dat}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
         xtick=data,
      ]
      \addplot table[
         x expr=\coordindex,
         y expr={
            (\thisrow{col2})^2
         }
      ] {\datatable};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: What are those *usual conventions* you speak of? To me this is not intuitive, but that is also not the real point. What I find strange is that `\thisrow{..}` is not somehow automatically parenthesised. If I attempt to square a value, I would expect it to work on both negative and positive numbers. I am looking for a rationale behind this.

Comment: @oarfish Math conventions. Keep in mind that TeX does macro expansion, the parsing of expressions is done by PGF at a later stage.

Comment: @oarfish This is an old issue and discussed with the authors some time ago on the [TikZ/PGF Sourceforge bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/147/) And as egreg mentioned power operation has a priority over negation as a convention unless a grouping with brackets is used.

Comment: @oarfish is right, the convention to merely expand in text-form is not intuitive. I as author of `pgfplots` will address this issue eventually. Thanks for the report.